# Check if object is list of list in python?

Tags: python, list

Is there any ways we  can detect if an object is list in python using `type(obj)` --> `list`.

But how can we detect if the object is list of list of the form as:

```
[['a','b']['a','b'][][]]
```

Answer (score 54):

Use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check for a specific type:

```
>>> isinstance([], list)
True
```

Use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to test if *all* elements are of a certain type:

```
all(isinstance(elem, list) for elem in list_of_lists)
```

`all()` short-circuits; if any of the tests returns `False`, the loop is terminated and `False` is returned. Only if all but one element returns `True` does `all()` need to examine every element of the iterable.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make sure that *every* item in your list is a list, you could do something like this:

```
if all(isinstance(i, list) for i in lst):
    # All of the items are lists
```

- `isinstance(i, list)` is the better way of writing `type(i) == type(list)` or `type(i) == list)`.
- `all()` returns `True` if all of the items in the sequence are `True`. It'll return `False` if any aren't `True`.

Comment: `type(i) == type(list)` newer works anyway. :-P `type(i) is list` can have some merits; it tests for the *exact* type (no subclasses allowed).