# Flatten parts of list

Tags: python, list, flatten

I have this piece of code that creates a list of lists of size 3. The problem is that some of these lists of lists are size 1 and are nested in this manner:

```
[[['b']]]
```

And are found inside another list. Is there anyway of flattening only part of the lists of lists to remove these lists of size 1 from being nested(regardless of how nested they are) but maintaining them as lists? Here are 2 examples:

```
d = [[['a']], 'to', ['b']]
```

would become:

```
d = [['a'], 'to', ['b']]
```

and

```
d1 = [[['c']], 'from', [['a'], 'to', [['b']]]]
```

would become:

```
d1 = [['c'], 'from', [['a'], 'to', ['b']]]
```

I have tried to use isinstance and seeing if the list is nested and then replace the value at that index, but that has not been successful. Instead, my code has been replacing all the values and flattening the list, which is not my intention. I only wish to reduce nested lists of size 1 to a single list. This was my attempt:

```
for index, value in enumerate(d1):
    if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 1:
        d1[index] = d1[index][0]
```

Comment: First of all read the docs about "isinstance".

Comment: What do you think `isinstance([], value)` does? Try `isinstance(value, list)`

Comment: @Mark the unbalanced brackets have been fixed, it was a mistake on my part.

Comment: @Mad Physicist I have just changed the code and tried this, but it still does not work. Do you have any suggestions as to how to approach this problem?

Comment: @learningtoprogram123. It does if you fix the blatant unclosed paren...

Comment: "It does not work" is not a valid problem statement. You did a good job listing expected results, but not the actual behavior that constitutes "not working"

Comment: @Mad Physicist
Well the problem is that the line:
d1[index] = d1[index][0] turns a value like:
[['b']] into 'b'. Is there anyway of just returning the list value within in this manner:
['b']

Comment: @Mad Physicist
And the reason I was using isinstance([], value) is that in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367848/check-if-object-is-list-of-list-in-python
It states that to test if you have a list of lists you write:
isinstance([], list). Therefore, when I was calling if(isinstance([], value), it was to check if the value was a list. Then if it was I wanted to replace it with the inner list.

Comment: @learningtoprogram123. You misunderstood the post. `isinstance([], list)` is always True. `list` is the type or class. `[]` is an example of an object you want to test. No worries, that's how you learn.

Comment: @Mad Physicist Sorry I have been working on several projects and I thank you for helping me out. My lack of upvoting is not due to carelessness or selfishness, but rather forgetfulness. Thank you for help.

Comment: @learningtoprogram123. No worries at all. You only gained the ability recently to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example you have lists inside of lists inside of lists (3 levels of nesting) that you want to flatten. But your code is only looking at 2 levels of nesting: `d[index]` and `d[index][0]` so your solution is only going to work on the outermost layers of nesting. Likewise your code will fail on an input like `[[[[[1]]]]]`. To fix it you'll need to generalize your solution so that it doesn't need to know or care how many levels deep the nested lists go.

Here's a solution using a recursive function - it's not the only way to solve the problem but it's the easiest to reason out, IMO.

```py
def flatten(lst):
    # base case: if input is not a list, just return it
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return lst

    if len(lst) == 1:
        if isinstance(lst[0], list):
            # if input is a 1 element list and that element is itself
            # a list, then flatten it
            return flatten(lst[0])
        # ...otherwise return the input, it's already flattened
        return lst

    # when there are multiple entries in the input, flatten each
    return [flatten(x) for x in lst]
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the major problem I was encountering. Since my program did not know the level of nestedness, then it could not accurately obtain the value within the list. Therefore, a recursive solution to traverse the entire list solves this problem.